# How to make FileSystemWatcher more reliable

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm monitoring a folder on a network mapped drive using `FileSystemWatcher`. I know it can be janky and report repeated events and various other issues, but I'm also running into a problem of it reporting file modification before and my app not being able to open the file (as in, after receiving multiple `Changed` events, I try to open the file and get `FileNotFoundException`).

My current protection:

I keep a dictionary of per-filename timers and a list of things that were already processed:

```
    static private Dictionary<string, Timer> fileChangeTimeout = new Dictionary<string, Timer>();
    static private Mutex newFileHandlerLock = new Mutex();
    static private List<(DateTime, string)> recentlyHandled = new List<(DateTime, string)>();
```

Modifications are registered to fire after `waitTime` (3s) of no changes:

```
    private void ScheduleFileHandling(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e){
        newFileHandlerLock.WaitOne();

        if(fileChangeTimeout.TryGetValue(e.FullPath, out var timer))
            timer.Change(waitTime, Timeout.Infinite);
        else
            fileChangeTimeout[e.FullPath] = new Timer(HandleFile, e.FullPath, waitTime, Timeout.Infinite);

        newFileHandlerLock.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

No-more-writes delay timer finally runs out:

```
    private void HandleFile(object state)
    {
        newFileHandlerLock.WaitOne();
        // remove the timer
        // return if file in recentlyHandled with time difference < 10s
        // add file to recentlyHandled
        newFileHandlerLock.ReleaseMutex();
```

This eliminated all the issues I've had with files either being empty or not fully written. But even after all that delay I sometimes run into "file not found" situations which don't make sense. (the file is in the folder when checked manually)

Is there any way I can make this process more reliable, or do I have to resort to just retrying for a few seconds and hoping for the best?

Comment: Not like this. There aren't repeated events - every file size change is a `Change` event, while preallocating the file results in just 2 Change events. Blocking will only result in lost notifications. Finally, there's no `Close` event so you have no idea of knowing if a file is still opened, eg for reading, or not. And temporary files may get deleted before you had a chance to process them

Comment: In this case only one application creates the files there and I'm sure it writes directly to the final path (verified with sysinternals process monitor) - there are no temporary files involved.

Comment: You can post all events directly to a Channel<> to avoid losing events. After that, you can wait for file activity to quiet down before processing the files. It may be enough just to wait for all activity to die down before proceeding. Or you may keep a timestamp per file.

Comment: If the file is still open you won't be able to read it, unless it was explicitly opened for sharing.